# How should I save custom game files using Java?

Tags: java, netbeans, save

I want to create a Pokemon-like game involving a few basic objects such as people, spells, potions, and different maps, which will really just be a grid with each square containing either a person or an image (like grass). Since creating all of these objects by coding them line by line would be tedious, hard to visualize (especially the map), and difficult to modify I plan on using the Net Beans IDE to create a GUI that will allow a user to create the objects previously mentioned.

Here's my problem: once I figure out how to get the map information that a user inputs using the GUI, how should I go about saving it in a form that can be read by the Pokemon-like application? Is there some sort of standard method for saving objects to a file and then reading then back in another application? Or am I taking the wrong approach here?

I'm using this project to learn more about programming in Java and have just started playing with Net Beans; forgive me if it sounds like I don't know what I'm talking about because I probably don't. Sorry that this question is so vague, but I have no idea where to start when it comes to saving mass amounts of objects to a file in an organized fashion and was simply hoping for some guidance on how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the sounds of it, Java serialization would be a good fit for your problem.  The only catch is that all of the objects in your graph the you want to serialize need to implement the `Serializable` interface ... and some library class don't implement it.  (For instance, you can't serialize threads or GUI objects.)  The work-around is to use the `transient` modifier to keep non-serializable objects out of the graph of objects to be serialized.

Here is the documentation index for Java Serialization:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/serialization/index.html

and here is the Java Tutorial section on the topic ... which is probably a better place to start if you are new to Java.

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/objectstreams.html

Answer (score 0):

Look into basic file i/o in java from their documentations here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/io/index.html and also large amounts of objects are best stored using Serialization: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html